# How to exclude cypress .cy.tsx files from build using Vite

Tags: typescript, cypress, vite

I have created some component tests using Cypress, `Component.cy.tsx`. For now the test files are located in the relevant component directory.

```
.
└── Component
    ├── Component.tsx
    └── Component.scss
    └── Component.cy.tsx
```

In addition, while installing Cypress it created a folder in root directory of my project.

How can I tell vite to ignore all files with `*.cy.tsx` endings and the folder of cypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell Vite to ignore all files with the *.cy.tsx extension and the Cypress folder, you can configure the vite.config.js file to exclude these files and directories from being processed by Vite's build process. You can achieve this by using the exclude option in the build configuration. Here's how you can do it:

Create or open the vite.config.js file in your project if it doesn't already exist.

Add the following configuration to exclude files with the *.cy.tsx extension and the Cypress folder:

```
// vite.config.js
export default {
  build: {
    // Exclude files with the *.cy.tsx extension
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: 'src/main.ts', // Adjust this to your entry file
        // Add other entry points if necessary
      },
      output: {
        // Your output options
      },
      // Exclude files with the *.cy.tsx extension from being processed by Vite
      external: ['**/*.cy.tsx'],
    },
  },
  // Exclude the Cypress folder from being processed by Vite
  exclude: ['cypress/**'],
};
```

In this configuration:

The external property in the rollupOptions is set to ['**/*.cy.tsx'], which tells Rollup (Vite's underlying bundler) to exclude all files with the *.cy.tsx extension.

The exclude property at the top level of the configuration tells Vite to exclude the entire Cypress folder from being processed.